# Styles only applying to some of the form field types

Tags: php, wordpress, html, css

My CSS styles are applying to `phone` and `submit` input types, but not to `text` and `email` types:-

```
#page_2_form input {
    background-color: green;
    width: 600px;
}
```

So to rectify it, I created another rule:-

```
#page_2_form input[type=text], input[type=email] {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 600px;
}
```

But it still won't work. Here is the HTML echoed in PHP:-

```
echo '<form action="/offer/details/results/" method="POST" id="page_2_form">';
echo '<h4>Who should we send this quote to?</h4><br>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' . $_POST["amount"] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="tenure" value="' . $_POST["tenure"] . '" />';
echo '<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name*"><br>';
echo '<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*"><br>';
echo '<input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*"><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Get My Monthly Repayments">';
echo '</form>';
```

Here is the form [live](http://testwebsitepage.club/offer/details/).

Please note that this is in Wordpress and I put the CSS via Custom CSS in Customize section.

Comment: after applying css to input field ,click `ctrl+F5` to front end it will remove the caching of page and load freshly. hope it will help you

Comment: That didn't help. 
P.S. I am already viewing it in private mode in firefox :)

Answer (score 2):

So I removed the PHP echos to isolate the HTML code.

It appears to have made the name and email fields (text and email) the correct color now. I hope this helps.

```css
#page_2_form input {
    background-color: green;
    width: 600px;
}

#page_2_form input[type=text] {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 600px;
}

#page_2_form input[type=email] {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<form action="/offer/details/results/" method="POST" id="page_2_form">
<h4>Who should we send this quote to?</h4><br>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="amount" />
<input type="hidden" name="tenure" value="tenure" />
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name*"><br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*"><br>
<input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Get My Monthly Repayments">
</form>
```

Comment: When I do it, the width of `text` and `email` fields is still smaller than the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the type specified rules come after the first *input rule. If that does not work, you can add !important after the rule:

```
#page_2_form input[type=text], input[type=email] {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    width: 600px;
}
```

But, you should avoid using !important unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: That worked with the `backgrond-color`, but not with `width`.

Comment: You can add !important after width as well, but you are prob better off figuring out why the type specified rule is not overwriting the global.

Comment: Yes I added `!important` to both and it only worked with `background-color`.

Comment: Yes, that's the dilemma.

Comment: @Grey-lover they are both 600px

Comment: Yes, but if you view the live version, only phone and submit are at 600px, the text and email aren't

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#phone{
        color: red !important;
      }
input[type='text']::-webkit-input-placeholder{
        color: red;
      }
```

Just modify it.

Comment: No, that didn't work I'm afraid.
PS. phone is not an id.

Comment: Just add something id's or class on your field so that you can assign it whether you can add color or not.. and also you can add the specific color to your placeholder of your choice.

Comment: As you can see. if you use input[type="text"] OR input[type="email"] it means ALL that has a type of text and email. imagine you have 50 text fields and you only want the 20 text fields that has a different color. what do you think will happen..

Answer (score 0):

```
Form 
<form action="/offer/details/results/" method="POST" id="page_2_form">
 <h4>Who should we send this quote to?</h4><br>
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="amount" />
 <input type="hidden" name="tenure" value="tenure" /> 
 <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name*"><br>
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*"><br>
 <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone*"><br>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get My Monthly Repayments">
 </form>
```

CSS:

```
#phone {
background-color: green;
width: 600px;
}

#phone::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: white;
}
#phone::-moz-placeholder{
    color: white;
}


#submit {
background-color: yellow;
width: 600px;
color: blue;
}
```

See Here https://jsfiddle.net/4ktgfv2t/

Answer (score 0):

You should put `padding` and `width` in together as:

```css
#page_2_form input,#page_2_form input[type=text],#page_2_form input[type=email]{
 width: 600px !important;
 padding: .7em .5em;
}

#page_2_form input {
    background-color: green;
   
}
#page_2_form input[type=text]
 {
    background-color: yellow;
   
}
#page_2_form input[type=email]
 {
    background-color: yellow;
    
}

We should avoid repeating anything like `width.`
```

```html
<form action="/offer/details/results/" method="POST" id="page_2_form">
<h4>Who should we send this quote to?</h4><br>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="amount" />
<input type="hidden" name="tenure" value="tenure" />
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name*"><br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*"><br>
<input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Get My Monthly Repayments">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

About width:
remove

```
max-width: 24.3em;
```

from style.css, 217 line

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=search], input[type=email], input[type=url], input[type=tel] {
    max-width: 24.3em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Or (better) set new one for your

```
#page_2_form input {
   max-width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I tried replacing `width` with `min-width` and it worked. Thanks everyone for their help though.